# Flash Media Server VS Sip Server: Difference for Voip

Tags: flash, webserver, voip, flash-media-server, sip

When using Flash Media Server and when using Sip Server ?

What is the difference  ?

What would you recommend ?

.

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

SIP Server is a VOIP Server that offers VOIP Access to clients, written for xample in java..
But since the SIP Server connects through HTTP one can build any client in any language and connect to the server. The advantage of the sip server is its connection protocol, which is based on the well known http connect protocol. SIP gives you status messages as you know them from apache ( e.g. 501 , 502, 502 ... where each number indicates a status ).

The FMS on the other hand is, in the newest version depending on the Server Type, a range between a Streaming Media Server up to a Streaming Server with interactive capabilities, such as realt-ime file sharing, peer-to-peer connections and collaboration with video conferencing. The FMS only suppports flash based rtmp connect protocol to connect. It offers a encryption protocoll for the channels, rtmpe. It also supports TLS security and role based authentication. A C(++) developer is able to code new plugins for FMS. See the sample authentication plugin.

Overall conclusion is, both servers are inherently different and not to be compared. Each server servers its own target group. The FMS has a very good Collaboration and Interaction API and is quite superb when using actionScript. The openSource alternatives such as RED5 are also quite good and worth checking out. Where RED5 is really the SHIT!!! 
FMS costs about 3500 a year++ depending on how many connections you want.
For the SIP Server I have no direct experience. Also it probably depends on the implementation... However I have read only good things about various SIP Server implementations.

- If you have still questions, drop me a mail to below mail address.

Given the tricky audio performance in FMS, the best solution would be to offer both servers to one client. Since the FMS has a http webroot a sip server may even be integrated into the fms ... UUh, what a nice idea for a sourceforge / googleproject... anybody interested in doing that? I have built one or two FMS applications so i can work on the fms part, all we need now is a SIP Server developer ;) 
If someone is seriouskly interested drop me a mail to atrocker@web.de.

Hope I could help you with that bit of information...

Cheers

Comment: The part about SIP is not correct. Even though SIP messages look similar to HTTP requests and responses, they're actually completely different. It's only the message syntax that is similar. SIP is a protocol on its own and does not connect in any way "through HTTP".